# Read-only file system error for chromedriver AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I am working on python selenium webscraper which also uploads data on database. It includes working with Chromedriver and headless chromium and I wish to deploy it on aws lambda .
I created a docker file and a container as well as image . The code runs perfectly on my local windows system inside the container.
When i tried to deploy container on Lambda function with help of ECR(Elastic Container Registery).
It throws many error when i test the function. First error thrown is :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/.local’:\
```

`touch: cannot touch '/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list': No such file or directory\`
`/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory\`
<
`Error creating Chrome driver: \[Errno 30\] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'`

## Cause of error :

Chromedriver couldn't install himself on AWS lambda directly due to read only file system. As I know we can install it in .\tmp direfctory. but I can't figure out how do i change the install location of both chromedriver as well as chrome binary.

Following are the codes which i used:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get clean && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt 
COPY . /app
CMD ["python", "LME_2.py"]
```

My **driver.py** file which handles all thechromedriver part.

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os
def return_driver(headless = True, logging = True):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")    
    if headless:
        options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--log-level=2")
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        print("Chromedriver started successfully.")
        return driver
    except Exception as e: 
        print(f"Error creating Chrome driver: {e}")
        raise
```

Any Solutions are appreciated !
Please reply if you need more overview of the code.
**Thanks**